# entrance of a graph and how nodes and edges linked together

Tags: algorithm, graph

I learned some graph theories like traversal, minimum spanning tree and so on. But just theories, I never use them when programming.

So I have two questions.

1. If the entrance of a tree is its root, then how about graphs? How can I keep tracking it after building it?
2. If I create an edge class to store some label or weight of an edge, how can I link every body together? How can I enter in a graph and can get to any edges and nodes?

I'm sorry if I asked dump questions, but graph is so fuzzy to me when it comes to programming.
And thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, tree and graph are both basic data structures in algorithm, you haven't use them usually, because you haven't face complicated practical problems. You can refer to this [https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19759/core-algorithms-deployed][1] to see how trees and graphs used in some famous open source softwares.

For your problem about Graph:

1. The entrance of a graph is always (Graph structure + entrance Node), Graph structure is the data and the relation which can describe the graph .e.g Matrix or Adjacency list. So when you use the Graph, begin with the entrance node you can operate on any Node or Edge according to graph algorithm.
2. Say you use a Matrix to store the graph, your input is:

   V1, V2, weight, you can represent this by a assignment, Matrix[v1][v2] = weight. The matrix has link every body together. When getting an edge, you can use Matrix[node1_of_edge][node2_of_edge]. And the node are represented by indexed integer.

I don't know if what I describe is understandable, I think if you are fresh to data structure and algorithm, you need to read more book and do more practice to understand the related data structure and algorithm perfectly. You just need to more imitating and thinking now!

Comment: Thank you very much. It's just what I learned in class was not at the programming level, so when I need to program something I get confused. What if I use adjacency list rather than matrix? Cause there are some other things I need to store. Do I need to create a field for the entrance node just like root to trees? @vmcloud